What's the offset of a float after a mat3 in a GLSL uniform block
I’ve been exploring mat3 alignment in GLSL and have encountered conflicting information that hasn’t been clarified by existing questions (such as this one).
Consider the following uniform block:
layout (set = 0, binding = 0) buffer Block {
    mat3 m;
    float s;
};

Given that each column of a mat3 is aligned to 16 bytes, the offsets for m’s columns are as follows:

1st column: 0 bytes
2nd column: 16 bytes
3rd column: 32 bytes

The confusion arises with the offset of s. Some sources suggest treating a mat3 as three vec4s, implying that s’s offset would be 48 bytes. Others propose viewing it as three vec3s aligned to 16 bytes each, which would place s’s offset at 44 bytes, because the last column of m occupies only 12 bytes.
Which interpretation aligns with the std430 layout specification for GLSL?

Not an answer, but you should really, really do everything do not use any vec3 / mat3 & co. in an UBO. You'll thank yourself for using vec4 / mat4 instead approximately thrice an hour once you'll start doing this.
